# lazy load google maps doesn't show map on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I've decided to play around with [this jquery example](http://osvaldas.info/lazy-loading-google-maps). I put the `jquery.js` and [`jquery.lazy-load-google-maps.min.js`](http://osvaldas.info/lazy-loading-google-maps) on my server in the `js/` folder and I put the `php` page that has the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lazy-load-google-maps.min.js"></script>
<script>
    ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
    {
        $( '.google-map' ).lazyLoadGoogleMaps(
        {
            callback: function( container, map )
            {
                var $container  = $( container ),
                    center      = new google.maps.LatLng( $container.attr( 'data-lat' ), $container.attr( 'data-lng' ) );
 
                map.setOptions({ zoom: 15, center: center });
                new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map });
            }
        });
 
    })( jQuery, window, document );
</script>
</head>
<body>
first:<div class="google-map" data-lat="40.7056258" data-lng="-73.97968"></div>
second:<div class="google-map" data-lat="51.5072113" data-lng="-0.1144521"></div>
third:<div class="google-map" data-lat="31.2243489" data-lng="121.4767528"></div>
fourth:<div class="google-map" data-lat="48.8588589" data-lng="2.3470599"></div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

but after running it in the browser all I see is:

> first: second: third: fourth:

Nothing else. Where is the problem?

Comment: You're running your scripts before the `div`s have loaded. Move your scripts to the end of the page, or [use `$(document).ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: I put scripts after divs, but the result is the same...

Comment: You have no div for the map.

Comment: Could you give me an example what exactly is wrong here with lack of divs? I still don't see it.. Thanks!

Comment: [My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7bc4fgnu/) suggests that the callback function is never executed. You might need to take this up with the plugin's author.

Comment: Wow ok, thanks. I just wonder how exactly does it work on the authors example page http://osvaldas.info/examples/lazy-loading-google-maps/